# Execute shell commands with arguments with `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`

Tags: java, coldfusion, processbuilder, cfml, railo

I have the following script that executes a shell command with Java's `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` that works ok if I don't use arguments:

```
<cfif IsDefined("FORM.cmd")>
  <cfif Server.OS.Name CONTAINS "Mac" or Server.OS.Name CONTAINS "Linux" or Server.OS.Name IS "UNIX">
    <cfset cmd = "sh -c #FORM.cmd#">
  <cfelseif Server.OS.Name CONTAINS "Windows">
    <cfset cmd = "cmd.exe /c #FORM.cmd#">
  <cfelse>
    <cfset cmd = "sh -c #FORM.cmd#">
  </cfif>

  <cfscript>
    str = htmleditformat(REReplace(cmd,"""","'","ALL"));
    exec = str.split(" ");
    pb = createObject("java","java.lang.ProcessBuilder").init(exec);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    proc = pb.start();
    proc.waitFor();
    isr = createObject("java","java.io.InputStreamReader").init(proc.getInputStream());
    br = createObject("java","java.io.BufferedReader").init(isr);
    line = br.readLine();
    while (isDefined("line")) {
     writeoutput(line & '<br>');
     line = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
    isr.close();
  </cfscript>
</cfif>
```

If my `#FORM.cmd#` is `uname`, the output is as I expect:

`Linux`

but if my `#FORM.cmd#` is `uname -a` the scripts executes only `uname` leaving outside the `-a` argument. So I thought I would use a java array to add arguments:

```
  <cfscript>
    args = createObject("java", "java.util.ArrayList").init();
    args.add("sh");
    args.add("-c");
    args.add("uname");
    args.add("-a");
    pb = createObject("java","java.lang.ProcessBuilder").init(args);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    proc = pb.start();
    proc.waitFor();
    isr = createObject("java","java.io.InputStreamReader").init(proc.getInputStream());
    br = createObject("java","java.io.BufferedReader").init(isr);
    line = br.readLine();
    while (isDefined("line")) {
     writeoutput(line & '<br>');
     line = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
    isr.close();
  </cfscript>
```

Same problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing to do with your error, but typically stream(s) are read first, to avoid filling up the buffer and/or blocking. Then waitFor is invoked. In the actual code, you might also want to a) capture the exit code from waitFor to determine if the process succeeded or failed and b) use a finally clause to ensure the streams are always closed, even if an unexpected error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"-a" is being passed in as an argument to sh, not to uname. You need to put "uname -a" within the same arg, ie:

```
args.add("sh");
args.add("-c");
args.add("uname -a");
```

If it helps clarify, to do this directly from the command line, you would want to type:

```
sh -c "uname -a"
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, for the second code of mine, in the other doesn't work, but I can take it as answered.